# AWS RDS, Lambda, API Gateway - Data not returned to API Gateway

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

I am trying to query some data from an AWS RDS Mysql instance, process it, and return it via API Gateway.
My overall process flow is: API Gateway -> Lambda -> RDS MySql

My code follows the following logic :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createPool({

    host: process.env.RDS_LAMBDA_HOSTNAME,
    user: process.env.RDS_LAMBDA_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.RDS_LAMBDA_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.RDS_LAMBDA_PORT,

});

exports.handler = (event, context,callback) => {

    var sql_query = 'SELECT * from Table';

    connection.query(sql_query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error->" + err);
            }
            else
            {
                result = do_some_processing(result);

                var response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: result };

                connection.end();
                callback(null,result);
            }
    });
};
```

The actual 'sql_query' is a bit more complex and has to be formed like this.

I added various console.log() statements to verify that the response object is getting formed and printed properly. On testing the Lambda function, I can see the correct response. However, on triggering the same function from 
API Gateway, I do not get any data back.

Following various instructions online, I have given all the possible permissions required for this(VPC role, RDS role, etc.).

Also, I have tried keeping Lambda and RDS in the same security group as well as separate security groups. The results remain the same.

This seems to be a fairly straightforward use case but I cannot get any response back.

Comment: Your function works on aws web console's "test" functionality but not working on api gateway when you try to make a request to gateway endpoint right ? Did you make async connection on api gateway/lambda integration ? Did you try to make an empty lambda returns only "hello world" and connect that to api gateway ? Did you try async/await ?

Comment: @Ersoy Yes, I did. 
If I try to return a static result, still does not reach API Gateway even though I can see the result is formed in the execution logs. I did try to set the exports.handler function as async. Still the same result. 
On trying with async/await, the result was being formed but the Lambda function itself was getting timed out. I verified this by increasing the timeout values as well. It turns out I was not closing the connection to SQL properly. I fixed that and still the result does not reach API Gateway.

Comment: probably you didn't configure integration between gateway and lambda, maybe you didn't "deploy" after saving all those changes on api gateway ?

Comment: @Ersoy I've been making sure to deploy changes simultaneously and multiple times. The API gateway logs show you 'before' and 'after' each template is applied but there is no data coming in. I am trying to figure out if I am doing something wrong with the callback or am I missing something in the MySQL node package.

Comment: if it is working on aws console's test function properly - but not working when you are using via gateway then it has to be related to lambda-gateway integration.